# What is meant by "Add project to working sets" in eclipse neon?

Tags: java, eclipse, project, working-set

I was starting with a new project in eclipse Neon version 3. I came across with this option saying "Add project to working sets". What does it mean if i choose it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse's [Working sets](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcworkset.htm) let you group projects:

> Working sets group elements for display in views or for operations on a set of elements.

For a new projects to be added to set, you need to add it explicitly

> Newly created resources are not automatically included in the active working set.